# SPARQL query REGEX boundary in java returns empty

Tags: java, regex, web, sparql, jena

i'm new in SPARQL and Jena. Here i'm using Jena version 2.13. I would like to perform a SPARQL query from java web application with REGEX boundary `(\b)`. I'm using REGEX boundary to match and find exact word.

I'm running the same SPARQL query on protege too.

Here my SPARQL query in java :

```
                "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> "
                + "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "
                + "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> "
                + "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> "
                + "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "
                + "PREFIX : <" + CROSS_NS + "> "
                + "SELECT ((?FoodAndBeveragesRecipes) AS ?Resep)((?FoodAndBeverages) AS ?a) "
                + "WHERE{ ?FoodAndBeveragesRecipes :IngR ?_IngR."
                + " ?_IngR :HasIngredients ?FoodAndBeverages;"
                + ":UnitValue ?Value;"
                + " :MeasurementUnit ?Measurements;"
                + " :Ing_Type ?IngType." 
                + "FILTER regex(str(?FoodAndBeverages), \"\\b" + recipe + "\\b\")}"
                + " ORDER BY ?FoodAndBeveragesRecipes";
```

`recipe` is String variabel to store user input, it's received as a parameter.

When i perform the query, Jena returns an empty set (not even null pointer exception) while Protégé return/find the correct results.
I don't know if the problem is with the REGEX code or what.

I was wondering why my REGEX is not working correctly ? could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\\\\W` - yes, 4 . One level goes for Java to get `\\W` into SPARQL, the next level is the SPARQL string to leave exactly `\W`.

Answer (score 1):

Word boundaries are not included in the SPARQL regex flavor (which is the same as [XPath flavor](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax)).  Perhaps Protégé supports them as an extension, but Jena doesn't.  Try using `(^|\W)` and `(\W|$)` instead:

```
+ "FILTER regex(str(?FoodAndBeverages), \"(^|\\\\W)" + recipe + "(\\\\W|$)\")}"
```

The extra backslashes are there because the string has two layers of escaping: the Java string literal, then the SPARQL interpreter.

Comment: Thanks. i have tried your advice but the result is error.
 com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Lexical error at line 1, column 608.  Encountered: "W" (87), after : "\"(^|\\ . any idea?

Comment: I don't know, `\W` *is* supported.  Maybe an escaping issue?  Try using different quotes (`'` instead of `\"`).

Comment: i have tried that too, `+ "FILTER regex(str(?FoodAndBeverages), '(^|\\w)" + Spertanyaan2fix + "(\\w|$)')}" ` , the result still error : Lexical error at line 1, column 608. Encountered: "W" (87), after : "\'(^|\\" , another suggestion?

Comment: @Jere id suggest printing the query after you've concatenated all those steins, and showing that. It's very hard to diagnose escaping issues when there are two levels of escapes.

Comment: @Joshua, could you tell me more how to printing the query after i have concatenated all those steins, and showing it? is there any tutorial to do that?

Comment: @Jeje  It's pretty basic Java.  All I'm talking about is `String query = "PREFIX ..." + /* ... */ "...";  System.err.println(query);`.  That way we can see how all the escaping is working out.

Comment: @Jeje Joshua meant `strings` not `steins`, was a typo

Comment: ok, i have tried `System.err.println(query);`. this is the output : `.... PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2014/4/SouthSulawesiCulinaryRecipes#> SELECT ((?FoodAndBeveragesRecipes) AS ?Resep)((?FoodAndBeverages) AS ?a) WHERE{ ?FoodAndBeveragesRecipes :IngR ?_IngR. ?_IngR :HasIngredients ?FoodAndBeverages;:UnitValue ?Value; :MeasurementUnit ?Measurements; :Ing_Type ?IngType.FILTER regex(str(?FoodAndBeverages),  "\bair\b")} ORDER BY ?FoodAndBeveragesRecipes` . then what the next step ?

Comment: i think i know where the problems is. i'm comparing the SPARQL query from jena with SPARQL query from protege. there is missing one \ (escaping issues) in sparql jena. i write this SPARQL `+ "FILTER regex(str(?FoodAndBeverages), \"(^|\\\W)" + recipe + "(\\\W|$)\")}"` but didn't work. how could i fix that?

Comment: if i write like this `+ "FILTER regex(str(?FoodAndBeverages), \"(^|\\W)" + recipe + "(\\W|$)\")}"`, it's missing one \ and the result is empty. and if i write like this `+ "FILTER regex(str(?FoodAndBeverages), \"(^|\\\W)" + recipe + "(\\\W|$)\")}"`, it's give me error illegal escape character. could anyone help me to fix that?

Comment: You need `\\\\W` - yes, 4 \.  One level goes for Java to get `\\W` into SPARQL, the next level is the SPARQL string to leave `\W`

Comment: And I thought Java alone was annoying!  I finally found another source to confirm this requirement, so I updated the answer.  Thanks, @AndyS.

Comment: My comment upgraded to an answer.